# How is the commented out require still working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, coffeescript, connect-assets

I was encountering a cofeescript page, when i happened to bump into a `require` syntax like `#= require something`
It is not a commented out required syntax, and removing the `=` breaks the build.
The project seems to be using angular, with coffee script , connect assets and jade.
here is the [link](https://github.com/souparno/plunker_www/blob/master/assets/js/apps/editor.coffee#L5) to one of the files.
can anybody explain me what is happening in here?

Comment: Please place the relevant code directly into your question, instead of linking to an external file that may disappear or change at any time.

Comment: It would also help if you reported the errors from the broken build.

Comment: That looks like [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets) or a similar preprocessor/packager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that this is a rack based package management system that comes shipped with connect-assets